# sed replacing string in quotes; with backreferences; shell script

Tags: shell, sed, zsh

I've been working on this for far too long, so I suspect I'm missing something fundamental.

I'm sorry that this may be well-documented, but I've read and I'm still not getting it.

I'm trying to replace a date on a line. The original line reads:

`date = "2020-11-01"`

I'm trying to replace that date with today's date, so I have:

```
text_date="$(date +%Y\-%m\-%d)"
sed -i 's/(date = ")*(")/\1'"$text_date"'\2/g' "$post_dir"/index.md
```

I have tried escaping the spaces and the quotes (and the equals sign) and I just feel v frustrated.

I'm getting an error presently:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 33: invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS
```

any idea of what may be going on? thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

In bash, the quotes act more like switches that control character expansion by
the shell than the start and end of strings (see [this great site](https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Quote.html) for a detailed explanation). Therefore you can can 'turn off
the single quotes (which prevent expansion), place your new data, then 'turn
the single quotes back on':

```
sed 's/\(date = \).*/\1"'$(date +%Y\-%m\-%d)'"/' your_file
```

Once you've confirmed this is doing what you want, you can add the `-i` to do
the substitution in-place:

```
sed -i 's/\(date = \).*/\1"'$(date +%Y\-%m\-%d)'"/' your_file
```

Comment: You can also use `-r` or `--regexp-extended` switch to be able to use capture groups like `\(date = "\)` without escaping parenthesis.

Comment: Thanks for these tips! (I'm still learning sed so I'll go and play around with what you suggest)

Comment: On my system (macOS, which has an ancient version of sed), `-i` needs an explicit argument: `sed -i '' 'cmd' ...` (deleted and re-added my comment; the prior one had an error).

Answer (score 0):

Bash expansion requires double quotes as opposed to single quotes. The issue is that there are double quotes in the text and so these will need to be escaped:

```
sed -rn "s/(^date = \")(.*)(\".*$)/\1$(date +%Y\-%m\-%d)\3/p" <<< 'date = "2020-11-01"'
```

Use -r to allow regular expression interpretation and then split the text into three sections using parenthesis. Replace the text with the first section, the expansion of the date command then the third section.

Comment: thanks so much! couple questions...

why would I need to capture the original date? why do I need `.*` when `*` would grab everything, right? what is the purpose of the `<<<` and stuff after it? I want this to be able to work no matter what the original date is in the file.

Thank you again!

Comment: <<< is simply redirecting the text date = "2020-11-01" back into sed to process as a stream.  When interpreting with regular expressions you will need to use .* to signify anything from opening speech marks to the closing speech marks. This in effect will be a place holder for any date (the second section which we replace with the expansion of the date command)

Comment: If the solution meets your requirements, please take the time to up vote the solution and accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your original post isn't too far off. Changes that made it work on my system:

- Escaped the parentheses for the capture groups: `(` -> `\(`, `)` -> `\)`
- Made the wildcard work in a regex: `*` -> `.*`
- Added an explicit in-place extension: `-i` ->  `-i ''`

The result:

```
text_date="$(date +%Y\-%m\-%d)"
sed -i '' 's/\(date = "\).*\("\)/\1'"$text_date"'\2/g' "$post_dir"/index.md
```

You may want to make the substitution pattern more explicit, to avoid changing any lines in the file that are similar but not an exact match. This version adds checks for digits in the date, and uses `^` and `$` to ensure that the pattern is the only thing on a line:

```
sed -i '' \
    's/^\(date = "\)[12][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[01][0-9]-[0-3][0-9]"$/\1'$(date +%Y-%m-%d)'"' \
    "$post_dir"/index.md
```

This doesn't use `-r`, since the default version of `sed` on macOS doesn't support it. As other answers have noted, that can make the command a bit cleaner.